# Convert array to array of const in Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, type-conversion, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am looking for a simple and ideally general (or using generics) way to convert an `array` to an `array of const` (=`array of TVarRec`). My specific case is that I have an `array of Variant` and want to pass it to the `Format()` function.

This is what I've found so far, but it looks hackish to me:

```
function MyFormat(const Fmt: string; const Args: TArray<Variant>): string;
var
  A: array of TVarRec;
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(A, Length(Args));
  for I:= Low(Args) to High(Args) do begin
    A[I].VType:= vtVariant;
    A[I].VVariant:= @Args[I];
  end;
  Result:= Format(Fmt, A);
end;
```

It seems to work. Is it safe?

Could it be done shorter, better, faster, or can I use something ready instead? :)

---

Just some additional thoughts and fun facts:

`System.Rtti.TValue` recently became my friend. However, it seems it is missing a feature here. I am able to read my array using `TValue.From()`, but it seems there is no way to get it out as `array of TVarRec`. There is a wonderful `TValueArrayToArrayOfConst`, but it doesn't really help, because I had to construct an `array of TValue` first, which is different from an array stored in a single `TValue`... :(

At least TValue is able to output a single element as TVarRec, so I thought I could create a generic converter for all types of arrays. But...

Would you think this works?

```
for I:= Low(Args) to High(Args) do A[I]:= TValue.From(Args[I]).AsVarRec;
```

It compiles, but `TValue`'s memory is released after use, and since `TVarRec.VVariant` is a pointer, it then points to some old location which is overridden on next cycle.

Comment: This is how TVarRec works: just a pointer to existing content. So you need to have the variables allocated during the sub-function call.

Comment: Yes, it is safe. There is no shorter way, AFAIK.

Comment: See the [definition of `TVarRec`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TVarRec) and read [Array of const](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html#arrayofconst) for an explanation of how `TVarRec` works. Your code "works" because `TVarRec` really does pass around a `Variant` by pointer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because safer, shorter, faster is not suitable for SO

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, last time I asked a question and put my solution to an answer, hoping for other/better answers. You didn't like it. Now I did not answer my own question and put everything I found directly into the question. You still don't like it. So you say it's better just asking the question and not mentioning what I've found so far? I guess then your next issue is that I didn't provide enough background. That all makes no sense to me. How should I ask my question so that you can accept it? The question is in the title (if you prefix it with "how to").

Comment: Of course, asking for a better (shorter/nicer/faster) solution is suitable for SO. It's what most questions implicitly want. People post answers, other people post better answers and votes help to decide which one is better than others. That's also why I like posting one of my own solutions as answer, so it can be voted for.

Comment: No, shorter / better / faster doesn't fit here. This is the wrong place to argue about it. Take that to meta.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, again I feel you are reading from bottom to top. There is a main question. Perfectly suitable. Then there is an example of what I have found so far. Then there is a secondary question "is it safe". Still ok? After that I just wrote "can it be done better" to remind that the question is in the title and it is not enough just to answer the secondary question "is it safe". So you want to close the whole question just because a tertiary question contains some words you don't like. I think my intention is clear and pretty ok for SO, how can I edit it to make it acceptable for you?

Comment: That discussion is for meta

Answer (score 5):

Your function is safe and fast. It only allocates a small memory array `A[]`, and passes all values by reference. I can't think on anything faster - without being premature optimization. I may only do some refactoring to reuse the `TArray<variant>` into `TArray<TVarRec>` conversion routine.

Using `TValue.From().AsVarRec` will definitively be slower, if your input is indeed a `TArray<Variant>`.

About `TVarRec` dandling references, you are right: those structures are just simple pointers on the stack, with no allocation, so all the referred variables should be available during the function call. So if you use a `TArray<TVarRec>` local conversion, you should ensure that the `TArray<variant>` is still allocated when calling the `format()` function.

Comment: Yes, I have exactly an array of Variant, and wanted to pass it to the `Format()` function. However, a general / generic solution (like if `TValue` would support it) would be even nicer. I don't like having to write so much code just to convert one array to another (even if the shorter solution is slower).

Comment: If you want less typing, as I suggested, make "some refactoring to reuse the TArray<variant> into TArray<TVarRec> conversion routine" as a stand-alone function. TValue seems clearly out-of-scope here, since you are already using variant values as containers.

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward and short solution (in code). If your formatstring (fmt) and array of values (sa) are unknown.

```
setlength(sa,5);      // or more
result := format(fmt,[sa[0],sa[1],sa[2],sa[3],sa[4]];
```

Comment: That's not a general way, because it only works for arrays of length 5.

Comment: Yes and no. If you know your formatstring never takes more then N arguments you can set the length to N (5 in example). Format uses only as much arguments as it needed. You can reset the length of the array afterwards if necessary. Probably not the Royal way but you also asked for an easy way.